# Add data in many to many tables

Tags: c#, sql, .net, visual-studio, .net-framework-version

I just started to learn to code at work and I have to create an application with books and authors. I created 3 tables book, author and book_by_author. I added some data in the author table and I have to create a view for adding data for the book, but the author should be chosen from a drop-down list after I write the book title.
[Check picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y3Tjz.png)
The problem is that I don't know how to do that and what code should I write.

DataBase code:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[book] (
    [Id]    INT           IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [title] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[author] (
    [Id]   INT           IDENTITY (0, 1) NOT NULL,
    [name] NVARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[book_by_author] (
    [Id_author] INT NOT NULL,
    [Id_book]   INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [FK_book_by_author_ToTableAuthor] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_author]) REFERENCES [dbo].[author] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_book_by_author_ToTableBook] FOREIGN KEY ([Id_book]) REFERENCES [dbo].[book] ([Id])
);
```

Model code:

```
namespace MVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Web.Mvc;

    public partial class book
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public book()
        {
            this.authors = new HashSet<author>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<author> authors { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace MVC.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;

    public partial class author
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public author()
        {
            this.books = new HashSet<book>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Author name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<book> books { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SchaefflerBibliothèque_MVC.Models;

namespace SchaefflerBibliothèque_MVC.Controllers
{
    public class booksController : Controller
    {
        private librarydbEntities db = new librarydbEntities();

        // GET: books
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.books.ToList());
        }

        // GET: books/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            book book = db.books.Find(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: books/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.AuthorSelect = db.authors.Where(n => n.name != null).Select(n => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = n.name,
            });
            return View();
        }

        // POST: books/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,title")] book book)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.books.Add(book);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: books/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            book book = db.books.Find(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(book);
        }

        // POST: books/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,title")] book book)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(book).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(book);
        }

        // GET: books/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            book book = db.books.Find(id);
            if (book == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(book);
        }

        // POST: books/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            book book = db.books.Find(id);
            db.books.Remove(book);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used `System.Web.Mvc` before, but I think I still might be able to help get you started. I'll focus first on querying the data from the database. You're looking for a list of `Author`s, so you'll need a DB query something like: `SELECT id, name FROM authors`.

Which will retrieve all rows from the `authors` table, with each row having and `id` and `name`. Luckily, you're using an web framework that can do this for you, and you even have an example at hand.

Looking at your current code, we can see how `Book`s are defined in the Models that represent the database representation of "a Book" in C# and how they are retrieved in the Book controller and passed to a View for rendering:

```
View(db.books.ToList());
```

This is completely analogous to what you're looking to do with `Author`!